# Is it possible to concatenate a variable to an if statement in Twig?

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to concatenate a variable to an array key to get access to certain values in Twig, but no success so far.

I have a large PHP array that has for example keys like this:

```
$array = [
   ...
   ...
   ...
   'test_1' => $test_1,
   'test_2' => $test_2
];
```

I tried the following in my Twig template:

```
{% for i in 1..2 %}

   {% if array.test_{{ i }} != 0 %}
      <div>Test</div>
   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to access values like this in Twig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for i in 1..2 %}
    {% if array['test_' ~ i] != 0 %}
        <div>Test</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```